# print out if two conditions are met

Tags: python

What I want to do is modify the if statement that I have below for dT. Right now I have it printing out "Temperature" "dT" "Steady State" if dT is between -.5 and .5 but instead I want it to print out those three items only if the dT value is between -.5 and .5 for ten straight iterations. If not, it should just print out "Temperature" "dT" as the else statement suggests.

```
temperature = []
dT_tol = .5

# Read loop
for i in range(60):
    # Get the thermocouple reading on AIN0. 
    tempC = ljm.eReadName(handle, "AIN0_EF_READ_A")
    temperature.append(tempC)
    dT = temperature[i]-temperature[i-1]

    if -dT_tol<dT<dT_tol:
        print "Temperature:","%.3f"% temperature[i],"         " "dT:", "%.3f"% dT, "         " "Steady State" 
        sleep(1)
    else:
        print "Temperature:","%.3f"% temperature[i],"         " "dT:", "%.3f"% dT
        sleep(1)
```

Comment: So as long as 3 data points in a row are within range, then print data for each of them?  so .5, .49, .5, .59, .6, .4, .5, .59  would print .5, .49, .5, .59, .4, .5, .59?

Comment: I think you have a challenging puzzle.  See if my answer solves your problem

Answer (score 1):

Just use `if` instead of `for`. Also use `0.5` instead of `.5` for readability. Consider using `format` method for displaying strings, espesially if you're using Python 3x.

Comment: But how do I make it so that the condition is that dT is between the two values for ten straight iterations before it begins to print "steady state"? It appears that your way will give me a print out of "steady state" every time the dT value is between -0.5 and 0.5

Comment: You don't have `if` statement, but you ask how can you modify `if`. Read your code carefully. The `for` doesn't work as you use it.

Comment: My mistake, yes I should have an if/else loop as opposed to a for/else loop. However, I still have not accomplished what I have set out to do. I want the condition that the dT values have to pass the test for 10 straight iterations before displaying the added printout of "steady state".

Comment: We don't see data you have there in temperature. It suggests that you have there 60 indexes. Is that correct?

Comment: I do have 60 indexes

Comment: But I want the test for dT to pass 10 times (10 iterations) before printing out "steady state" each time

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you might want:

I am editing my answer with new code.  If this is the wrong thing to do, I'll delete this answer and add a new one.  My mind was close but kind of messy.

This code first finds all the places where the data is out of range and records their indices (stops).  It then checks from 'stop' to stop' to see if the range is greater than 2 and collects those values in the final results.

```
temp_list = []

# first make up some data.  These are all positive, between 0 and .7.  In your case you would use your temperature data
temp_list = [.6, .5, .4, .3, .5, .6, .4, .3, .2, .8, .4]
print "temp_list"
print temp_list

# we want to print data where at least 3 in a row are within -.5 and .5

print "---------"


results = []
stops = [(i, d) for i, d in enumerate(temp_list) if abs(d)>.5]
stops.append([len(temp_list), 10])
last_stop = 0
print stops

for pos in stops:
   if pos[0]-last_stop>2:
       results.extend(temp_list[last_stop+1:pos[0]])
       last_stop = pos[0]
       print results

print "done"
```

Results:

```
temp_list
[0.6, 0.5, 0.4, 0.3, 0.5, 0.6, 0.4, 0.3, 0.2, 0.8, 0.4]
---------
[(0, 0.6), (5, 0.6), (9, 0.8), [11, 10]]
[0.5, 0.4, 0.3, 0.5]
[0.5, 0.4, 0.3, 0.5, 0.4, 0.3, 0.2]
done
```

Comment: I used 3 instead of 10 in a row

Answer (score 0):

You can use a count variable, set the count variable to 0 whenever the condition has been hit 10 times in a row or the streak is broken

Comment: Could you prove an example of that? I am not familiar with this method

Comment: @AndrewPoissant i'm not trying to be condescending but it seems like you have essentially zero understanding of even the most basic of programming concepts. Perhaps you'll be better-served by taking some tutorials (there are plenty of free and inexpensive available online)

Comment: Saying that someone has essentially zero understanding of basic programming concepts is very condescending. I am accustomed to matlab and have knowledge of basic programming concepts. I am new to python and was looking for help, not an attack at my knowledge

Comment: It is condescending but he's not wrong you know...
MatLab is not an actual programming language and immersing yourself solely in that while only hurt you